# Time series data - calculate difference

Tags: r, time-series

### **Original question**

I am about to do an analysis of generic pharmaceutical drugs - more specifically I want to observe the development in price after the patent of a drug expires.

I have presented the data in the example below - *columns jan.2001 to dec.2001 represents the months in 2001* - under each column, I have the average price of a daily defined dosage of a generic drug in the given month. The drugs have each their own unique name represented by their ATC-code stated under the *ATC-column*.

I have another column named *expiry*, which states the month where the patent of a drug expired.

Can anyone tell me, how I can calculate the difference in price since the date listed in patent_expiry until the latest date (period 12 in the before mentioned example) for each ID?

### ***Updated question (incorporating Veera's solution):***

**Below is an example of my current data**

```
> head(dfm)
   ATC     expiry     jan.2001 feb.2001 mar.2001 apr.2001 maj.2001 jun.2001 jul.2001 aug.2001 sep.2001 okt.2001 nov.2001 dec.2001  res
1 A02BC01  feb.2001     11.9     11.9     12.0     12.0     11.8     11.9     11.9     11.9     11.8     12.0     11.9     11.9  0.0
2 A02BC02  jul.2001     11.8     10.9     11.1     11.3     11.2     11.0     11.5     11.1     10.8     11.0     10.5      8.4 -3.1
3 A02BC03  okt.2001      9.3      8.9      8.8      8.8      8.8      8.7      8.7      8.7      8.7      8.7      7.8      7.4 -1.3
4 A02BC05  nov.2001     10.6     10.4     10.6     10.6     10.5     10.5     10.4     10.4     10.6     10.5     10.4     10.4  0.0
5 A03FA03  nov.2001      5.4      4.9      5.0      4.5      4.4      4.5      4.6      4.3      4.4      4.4      4.9      5.1  0.2
```

**The final column 'res' is the solution to my original question**

```
> str(dfm)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ ATC     : Factor w/ 5 levels "A02BC01 ","A02BC02 ",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ expiry  : chr  "feb.2001" "jul.2001" "okt.2001" "nov.2001" ...
```

**My current code for the solution**

```
dfm <- read.csv2("aip.csv", header = T, sep = ";", dec = ",")

dfm$expiry = as.character(dfm$expiry)

# Generate formula to calculate the savings
calc = function(){
  res = integer(nrow(dfm)) 
 for (i in 1:nrow(dfm)){ 
   res[i] = dfm[i,"dec.2001"] - dfm[i,dfm[i,"expiry"]]
 }
 return(res)
}

# Insert calculation into data frame
dfm$res = calc()
```

I would like to generate a new data frame, let's call it savings, and calculate the savings for each succeeding month after the expiry month for a given ATC. I am thinking about something similar to this:

```
ATC     expiry       jan.2001 feb.2001 mar.2001 apr.2001 maj.2001 jun.2001 jul.2001 aug.2001 sep.2001 okt.2001 nov.2001 dec.2001
A02BC01  feb.2001     NA       NA      -0.1     -0.1      0.1      0.1      0.1      0.1      0.2      0.1     0.0      0.0
A02BC02  jul.2001     NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       0.4      0.7      0.5     1.0      3.1
A02BC03  okt.2001     NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       0       0.9      1.3
```

For example: The drug with the ATC-identifier A02BC01 went of patent in feb.2001. Now, I would like to calculate the difference in price from then compared to march, april, may, ..., december - essentially each month following the expiry month.

In the end, I would like to multiply the savings in each period with the volume of sales in the matching period, for the matching ATC. For example, for drug A02BC02:
(Price_expiry-price_december)*salesvolume_december

Which in the end, would calculate the amount of money saved in December sales due to the price decrease after the expiry-month. I have a data set with the defined daily dosis volume for all of the ATCs and dates matching the data set above (i.e. same structure as the price data set presented before).

Can you help me extend the solution to this?

Comment: The year is not relevant? The information  about month should not be enough... Furthermore, please give a reproducible example - then we can help.

Comment: Can you explain the last savings part a little more in detail ? What is the definition of "savings" here ?

Comment: I have tried to explain with a follow-up example in the bottom - and I have inverted the numbers, I could see why they were a bit confusing referring to "savings". Thanks again for your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't name the columns with numbers. Here is a simple example, by creating a function for that.

```
jan = sample(1:20,5)
feb = sample(1:20,5)
mar = sample(1:20,5)
apr = sample(1:20,5)
expiry = c("jan","feb","mar","apr","jan")
dfm = data.frame(jan,feb,mar,apr,expiry)
dfm$expiry = as.character(dfm$expiry)

calc = function(){
    res = integer(nrow(dfm))
    for (i in 1:nrow(dfm)){
              res[i] = dfm[i,"apr"] - dfm[i,dfm[i,"expiry"]]
          }
    return(res)
}
dfm$res = calc()

  jan feb mar apr expiry res
1   5   4  14  12    jan   7
2  19   3  12   5    mar  -7
3   2   6   5   6    apr   0
4   9  10  15  16    feb   6
5  16   7  20  15    jan  -1
```

Comment: Filling a vector piecewise is bad R, because in each iteration R has to reserve new space and copy all values. I added an initialization, although this problem should be solvable without a loop.

Comment: your suggestion, `res  = c(length = nrow(dfm))` is not right I am afraid. It is not defining the 'length' of the vector, it is just adding an element named length inside the vector `res`

Comment: You're right, it should be `res <- integer(nrow(dfm))`.

Comment: sorry, but still it's the same, it just adds an extra element but doesn't define the length of the vector. You could just run it R and check

Comment: Nonsense. From the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/as.integer): "`integer` creates a integer vector of the specified length. Each element of the vector is equal to 0."

Comment: I get your logic. But u missed editing the code inside the loop. I don't have enough reputation to modify your suggestion. So, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have incorporated your solution to my question, and updated the question with a better example and a follow-up question, that I hope you can help me with :-)